# Python3 set() keeps resetting itself within while loop

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, set, breadth-first-search

I encountered this issue while working on a basic graph traversal [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/).

I've included my entire answer below, a basic BFS. But my question really concerns to what is happening with my set() variable named "seen" in the while loop.

Basically, I initialize it to an empty set *before* the while loop, expecting it to cumulatively grow with each value popped from the queue being added to this set, from within the while loop.

Instead, it seems that on each iteration of the while loop, the contents of "seen" somehow revert back to being empty, despite not resetting it in the code.

I have added some comments to clarify where I'm referring to:

```
import queue

def canFinish(numCourses, prerequisites):
    prereqs = {}
    buildPrereqs(prereqs, prerequisites)
    
    for course in range(numCourses):
        seen = set() # initialize set outside of while loop
        q = queue.Queue()
        q.put(course)
        while (not q.empty()): # while loop 
            popped = q.get()
            print("popped:", popped)
            print("seen at beginning:", seen)
            if popped in seen:
                return False
            seen.add(popped) # populate set, but resets before next iteration (?)
            if popped in prereqs:
                for prereq in prereqs[popped]:
                    q.put(prereq)
            print("seen at end:", seen)
    return True


def buildPrereqs(prereqs, prerequisites):
    prereqs = {}
    for pair in prerequisites:
        course = pair[0]
        prereq = pair[1]
        if not course in prereqs:
            prereqs[course] = set()
        prereqs[course].add(prereq)

print(canFinish(2, [[1,0],[0,1]]))
```

If I run canFinish(2,[[1,0],[0,1]]), which is one of the example cases at the leetcode link, I get the following output from my print statements:

```
popped: 0
seen at beginning: set()
seen at end: {0}
popped: 1
seen at beginning: set()
seen at end: {1}
```

Whereas I am expecting something like this:

```
popped: 0
seen at beginning: set()
seen at end: {0}
popped: 1
seen at beginning: {0}
seen at end: {0, 1}
```

I tried using a dictionary in place of the set() and encountered the same thing. Can someone help me identify the source of this Python behavior?

Comment: What makes you think you're seeing the next `while` iteration, instead of the next iteration of the outer `for`?

Comment: (Don't use `queue.Queue` for single-threaded use cases, by the way. Despite the terrible name choice, it's not actually designed to be a general-purpose queue. It's designed to be an inter-thread message channel, and it has a lot of overhead and awkward design choices for a general-purpose queue use case. `collections.deque` is Python's general-purpose queue.)

Comment: Shoot, you're right. It's not the set, it's that the while loop is only executing once per for loop iteration. So now it makes sense, and set() is behaving as expected. My bug is that I initialize prereqs = {} again inside of BuildPrereqs(). Thank you @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: And okay, I did see a lot of thread-specific documentation on the Queue docs page so I understand now.. will use deque from now on!